# Google Earth Engine, imagecollection aggregate_max (or min, or min), return null. What's the problem?

Tags: google-earth-engine, aggregation

I am a little confused about this function in `ee.ImageCollection`:

> **aggregate_max(property)**
>
> Aggregates over a given property of the objects in a collection, calculating the maximum of the values of the selected property.

It returns NULL, and I do not know why. Here is the code:

```
// creat a function for clipping.
var clippedtoGulf = function(image) {
  return image.clip(geometry);
};


var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
  .map(clippedtoGulf)
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2017-03-01');

print('ndvi', ndvi)
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {}, 'ndvi')


var stats = ndvi.aggregate_stats('NDVI')    
var max   = ndvi.aggregate_max('NDVI')  
print('stats', stats)
print('max', max)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2ecef30aa9c1294af95eaaa53dccdf06

Answer (score 3):

Note that the documentation says that `aggregate_max` aggregates over the *properties* of the objects in a collection. The objects in your collection are images, and these images each have a *band* named "NDVI", but not a *property* named "NDVI".

You will need to `.map()` over the image collection to attach a property to it. You'll also need to do something to combine the values from the entire band to a single value, such as `reduceRegion` — presumably just another `max` is what you want.

For example, I modified your existing mapping function to find the maximum NDVI anywhere in any of the images, within your region:

```
var clipAndFindMaxNDVI = function(image) {
  var clipped = image.clip(geometry);
  var maxNDVI = clipped.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    scale: 1000,
  }).get('NDVI');
  return clipped.set('NDVI', maxNDVI);
};

var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
  .map(clipAndFindMaxNDVI)
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2017-03-01');

var max = ndvi.aggregate_max('NDVI');
```

Another approach would be to, instead of computing the max within the region for each image and then taking the max over the collection, compute an image which has the maximum over time, then reduce to get the maximum over space. This can be written more concisely because it doesn't require setting a property, but implies having to specify a coordinate system for the combined image:

```
print(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2017-03-01')
  .select('NDVI')   // don't care about other bands
  .max()            // turn collection into image, with each pixel being the max across the collection
  .reduceRegion({   // turn image into reduced values
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 1000,
  })
  .get('NDVI'));    // get the value from the dictionary
```

This is probably not better for the calculation you were attempting, but it might be useful in other circumstances if you have a use for the combined image.

Disclaimer: I'm not a GIS expert, I just work on Earth Engine. There may be bad ideas here to do with how the images are resampled, or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kevin! These two answers both work perfectly and the results are consistent! One more small question, why should we specify a coordinate system? As I see you did not do this for the first answer, and also I find the crs of the original imagecollection is the same as what you added to the second answer ('SR-ORG:6974').

Comment: @Yingjie It's not necessary, apparently. I'm still learning myself, and didn't fully explore what the minimum required parameters for this case are.